# Expo App Lock Authentication: Seeking Pattern/Password Access

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, frontend

I've built a React Native Expo app and implemented app lock authentication using [ExpoLocalAuthentication](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/local-authentication/). However, I'm only able to get fingerprint and face recognition access, not pattern or password. I've checked Expo modules but found none. Found a few React Native CLI modules for pattern or password authentication but not able to use them in expo. I'm thinking is there an option for app lock authentication with pattern or password? Any suggestions for Expo-specific solutions?